# Is negative offset address valid in addressing?

Tags: assembly, addressing

Hi I am taking up a course on 16-bit assembly programming using TASM and I would like to know if when the value inside a bracket or the address becomes negative, would it become an error or proceed accordingly?

e.g. BP=94F7h, SI=0EF89h
MOV AX,[BP+SI-0DFC1h]

the sum of BP and SI would be greater than 4-bits so another question comes into my mind, would I discard the 5th bit before proceeding to subtracting the displacement or still consider it?

Comment: Addresses cannot be negative, they are unsigned values.  They simply overflow with the 17th bit discarded.   The result is 0A4BFh.  A 16 bit value, not 4 bits.  The odds that the program will work correctly are rather slim, this looks like code produced by a random number generator.

Comment: The processor combines all the values involved in an indexing operation (e.g., the index register, any offset ) as 2's complement numbers (you call them negative, but that's just an opinion about what that bit string represents) essentially by adding them.  Whateever the final sum, it becomes the address.

Comment: thanks for answering guys. sorry for the late reply though